# SafeArea not working in persistent bottomsheet in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using MaterialApp and Scaffold + SafeArea for screens. All works well until I try to use persistent BottomSheet. BottomSheet content igores SafeArea and are shown below system controls, for example in iPhone X.

I tried to wrap BottomSheet contents in another SafeArea element, but it did not help.

Is there a way to get the same functionality as SafeArea to work in BottomSheet? If yes then how?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Just try to create any persistant BottomSheet with showBottomSheet and run it on iPhone X.

Comment: You're asking people to do a lot of work to start helping you with your question.  You should create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, per the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Creating a BottomSheet is a lot of work? Instructions are clear on how to repeat this. If you can't help, then why comment?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to file an issue on github with the code and a screenshot. I guess it should work with SafeArea out of the box.

Answer (score 18):

Just make the root Widget of the *showModalBottomSheet* be a SafeArea Widget

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[...
```

[image]

Comment: Just `SafeArea` isn't enough. Be sure to set `top: false` for the `SafeArea` as well or BottomSheet will get top padding. Only with ignored `top` I was able to get the result as on the screenshot in this answer. Checked on Flutter 1.22.4.
P.S. Edited the answer to add `top` into the code snippet, but it will appear only after peer review.

Comment: @VolodymyrBuberenko for me, adding `SafeArea` with `top: false` was insufficient to prevent the bottom sheet from running over the normal bounds of `SafeArea` at the top of the screen.

Comment: @LukeHutchison My comment is quite old already and based on currently old Flutter version. Something might have changed. What helped you in the end?

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by adding container and padding inside with: `MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).padding.top`

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).padding.top),
      child: MyOriginalWidgetForBottomSheet(),
)
```

Don't get  from the context (like `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top`) as the padding always returns 0

Comment: This adds extra space to the top of the bottom sheet even if it only takes up half the screen. Not the right solution.

Comment: Thanks, took a day to find this. if set `useSafeArea: true` there will be a transparent space at the bottom on iphone 13. With this we can manually control our view's padding.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced this issue too. When I changed code from `showModalBottomSheet` to `_scaffoldKey.currentState.showBottomSheet` my `SafeArea` stopped working.

You can solve it with these steps:

1. create key for your Scaffold `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();`
2. assign created key to your Scaffold `key: _scaffoldKey,`
3. set bottom padding to your bottom sheet 
   `padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(_scaffoldKey.currentState.context).viewPadding.bottom)`

Here is a result, I also added 15 padding to top, left and right.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed -- just set `useSafeArea: true` in `showModalBottomSheet`. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39205

Answer (score 2):

In my case the top safe area was the problem and a practical workaround was to set padding to the height of the app bar with AppBar().preferredSize.height

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,AppBar().preferredSize.height,0,0),
          child: Text(
            'Your Order',
            style: headingMediumBlack,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out this simple code and it works as intended in the iOS Simulator with an iPhone X:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new SafeArea(
          child: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('SafeArea demo'),
            ),
            body: new Center(
              child: new TapMe(),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class TapMe extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text('Tap Me'),
      onPressed: () => Scaffold
          .of(context)
          .showBottomSheet((context) => new Text('I\'ve been tapped')),
    );
  }
}
```

What version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: I guess if you put the Scaffold itself in a SafeArea it works. But is it correct?

Comment: It is indeed incorrect. Toolbar becomes black and so does bottom area.

Comment: You're correct. I can try to modify the code, but I'm not sure what you mean by shown below system controls on an iPhone X. Can you give a screenshot to show what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue too with top-notch.

Resolved using `dart:ui.window.viewPadding.top / ui.window.devicePixelRatio`

How it works:
The `dart:ui.window.viewPadding` is the number of physical pixels on each side of the display rectangle into which the view can render.
By dividing to `ui.window.devicePixelRatio` we should receive logic pixels.

So in summary code is

```
showModalBottomSheet<bool>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
     top: ui.window.viewPadding.top / ui.window.devicePixelRatio,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, The cleanest workaround is to set `InitialChildSize` to **0.9**

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
  initialChildSize: 0.9,
  minChildSize: 0.2,
  maxChildSize: 0.9,
  expand: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
    
    }
)
```