# Safearea not working in showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Safearea() does not wrap the showModalBottomSheet properly. I need to show the modal under the status bar.

[image]

```
class ModalBottomSheet {
  static void renderModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(border2),
        ),
      ),
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            child: widget,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried the following solutions but it still doesn't work properly

```
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top


MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).padding.top
```

Update:

I managed to solve it this way.

add this to the bottomsheet

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

and padding top

```
top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
```

full code:

```
class ModalBottomSheet {
  static void renderModalBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            child: widget,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

your child widget can have the border radius and colors instead.

open keyboard

[image]

closed keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 14):

There's a new feature to fix this -- set `useSafeArea: true` in `showModalBottomSheet`. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39205

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If it doesn't work, refer this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49737225/11789675)

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[...
```

Comment: I have tried all the answers on that other question. but the modal still goes behind the status bar

Answer (score 0):

you should get `MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top` before `showModalBottomSheet` and pass it to sheet inside, then use `EdgeInsets.top` inside the sheet.

Comment: This just adds padding to the top of the bottom sheet, which shows even if the bottom sheet doesn't take up the full height of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you.

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: AppColors.transparent,
      builder: (context) {
        final safeAreaPadding = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).padding.top;
    
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: safeAreaPadding),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
            child: const _YourChild(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    
    class _YourChild extends StatelessWidget {
      const _YourChild();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
      }
    }
```